# Google Places - How to get latitude and longitude values

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Hi I have a simple input field for when a user enters their location and google autocompletes their address. I would like to attain their lat & long co-ordinate values also because I need to input them to my database. Any suggestions on how this can be done, please let me know?Thanks.

HTML -

```
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="" 
    required><br>
```

JS -

```
       function activatePlacesSearch() {
        var input = document.getElementById('location');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you add an event listener to your autocomplete in order to get information about selected place. Something similar to

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
    }

    var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

    //TODO: save coordinates to DB   
});
```

I hope this helps!